# Excel Vlookup to search for substring from one sheet to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

i have 2 excel sheets and i need to use vlookup to search a particular string from the first sheet and try to find it as a substring in the second sheet. If it matches the substring from the first sheet (the whole string) i would like to set it as True or False or 1 or 0. I have thousands of records so this has to be done automatically. Is there any way i could use vlookup to fetch data from the first sheet and find the same data as a substring in the second sheet automatically for all records please.

What i mean is this:

Sheet 1:

---

### | 1 | hello|

### | 2 | test |

### | 3 | abc |

Sheet 2:

---

### | 1 | abc123|

### | 2 | hello123456 |

### | 3 | test12 |

As they are substrings, they should be marked as true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MATCH with bracketing wildcards. If a match is found, it will return a number; if not then it returns a #N/A error.

```
'for TRUE/FALSE
=isnumber(match("*"&sheet1!a2&"*", sheet2!A:A, 0))
'for 1/0
=--isnumber(match("*"&sheet1!a2&"*", sheet2!A:A, 0))
```

[image]